# How to create cronjob which will back up current directory and send archive to FTP server?

Tags: linux, ftp, cron

How to back up all files inside directory (all tree folders and files) to archive and then send to ftp server? Can I do this using cronjobs? How should `tar` command look like to back up `/home/user/` directory and all files and folders inside to `/home/` with compression?

---

cd /my/very/interesting/and/important/directory & tar -cjf . backup.tar.bz2 --exclude & backup.tar.bz2 & sftp backup.tar.bz2 me@myserver
**as far as i understand is equal to:**

1. cd /my/very/interesting/and/important/directory
2. tar -cjf . backup.tar.bz2 --exclude
3. backup.tar.bz2
4. sftp backup.tar.bz2 me@myserver

   - what parameter `j` means in 2nd command?
   - probably there should not be a `&` between `tar -cjf . backup.tar.bz2 --exclude` AND `backup.tar.bz2`. Because `&`merges commands. Right?
   - what about password param in 4th command?

Comment: This kind of question are better to be asked here: http://superuser.com/

Comment: You are correct, the `&` between `--exclude` and `backup.tar.bz2` is a mistake. Read the `tar` manuals for description of the options.

Comment: Yes and no. The one-liner and the four-liner are equal in the sense that they do the same thing if nothing goes wrong, but there is a difference in that the one-liner stops if something goes wrong along the way, while the four-liner does not. See my updated answer.

Comment: Also, questions for clarification of answers are better asked as comments, unless they are part of the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cron job issues a command. If you can do it from the command line, you can to it with cron.

There are at least three simple ways to accomplish what you want:

- Create a shell script and run that.
- Write an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build script and run that.
- Simply stack all the needed commands after one another, separated by `&&`. However, I don't recommend this, see below.

This is an example series of skeleton commands that might be useful. This is more intended as a sketch of the concept rather than a comprehensive, working script. For instance, I'm not sure how to use `sftp` without having to manually enter a password, so I left that out. Look up the documentation for the commands used and figure out yourself what to use and how in your specific case, maybe you'll even learn something along the way. ;)

```
cd my-important-directory
tar -cpvf backup.tar -C .. --exclude backup.tar* my-important-directory
bzip2 backup.tar
sftp backup.tar.bz2 me@myserver
```

You could put the above commands in a shell script, or combine them into one command, like so:

```
cd my-important-directory && tar -cpvf backup.tar -C .. --exclude backup.tar* my-important-directory && bzip2 backup.tar && sftp backup.tar.bz2 me@myserver
```

This, however, is horribly ugly if you ask me. I'd go with the shell or ant script options to improve readability and avoid maintenance headaches. Those methods also make it easier to maintain in another way: you don't have to update the crontab every time you need to make a change to the backup script, just edit the script and you're good to go.

### The `&&` operator

Separating two commands with `&&` tells bash to run the second command if and only if the first command exits with status `0`, which is the standard exit code used when commands exit successfully. This may be compared to `;`, which can be used to run multiple commands in succession regardless of success or failure. Using `&&` means that the series of commands stops if something goes wrong along the way. For instance, if `tar` fails to create an archive, there's no use in attempting to compress that archive afterwards.

What really happens behind the scenes is short-circuit logic. `cmd1 && cmd2` is a logic statement that says "Return `true` if both `cmd1` and `cmd2` exit with exit code `0`, otherwise return `false`" (though `true` and `false` are actually represented by numbers). If `cmd1` doesn't exit with exit code `0`, then the logic statement is already `false`, and the statement returns `false` without running `cmd2`.

Comment: can I create a bash script on server and point cron to execute it?

Comment: On another server? I'd guess it's possible but might get a bit more complicated. It might be fairly easy to have your local script download a remote script and run it.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake! Suffixing with `&` tells the shell to run the command in the background, `&&` is the operator we want here.

Comment: What is the difference( & OR &&) when we scheduling a task using cron? Anyways it will run in background, right?

Comment: The difference is that `&` doesn't do what we need. `&&` is what we want, `&` is something completely different. And yes, even without `&` it will be run in the background in the sense that it won't be connected to YOUR shell, but it's still connected to cron, and not in the background if you ask cron. I don't know about the insides of cron but I suspect it usually waits one way or another for programs to exit, so backgrounding programs in cron jobs might be a bad idea unless you have a good reason to.